# Horizontal scroll using previous and next buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several lists to which I need scroll effect for each. I did that but when I click one list's arrow buttons, all lists seem to scroll. How can I target a specific list when the arrow of that list is clicked?

Comment: Post your code or more details if you want a good answer.

Comment: Sample code of my list is given here https://jsfiddle.net/vo1ty3db/  also the script I am using is mentioned. In my code on clicking arrows in div id="abc", I should be able to scroll only the list of that division and on clicking arrows in div id="def", I should be able to scroll only the list of that division.

Comment: That fiddle doesn't work.

Comment: I could not upload the whole code publicly to you as it has some issues. Can you give ur email so I can send to u

Comment: Hey I want the scroll type like as that of netflix that for several lists, there are buttons and clicking on the arrows of the list, that particular list is scrolled. Can anyone help me as soon as possible? Please!